# Custom Nav Menu Walker

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set a Wordpress Nav with my own css classes but I am getting compatibility issue again and again I tried to follow the different available results all looks same but I am not sure what causing this issue. Please help me to resolve this

```
Warning: Declaration of Selective_Walker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = NULL, $id = 0) in functions.php on line 69
```

Here is my `functions.php` code

```
class Selective_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
    {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }
        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        if ( $args->has_children ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'submenu';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `header.php` code where I want to expect the menu

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id' => '',
    'menu_class' => '',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'walker' => new Selective_Walker,
    'depth' => 0
    )
);
```

Expected Menu Structure

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="has_children"><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP tells you this

```
Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = NULL, $id = 0)
```

is not the same as this

```
Selective_Walker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
```

So you have to change your `start_el` method to:

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = NULL, $id = 0) {
```

### Why?

Because the base-class (`Walker_Nav_Menu`) relies on the `start_el` Method to not change its signature (parameters/data-types/default-values/return-type). If you would be able to overwrite the `start_el` with a different signature the code of the base-method is very likely to break.